# ASP.NET Core 6-7 Web API, Disable multipart/form-data model binding entirely (how to disable IFormFile bind?)

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, model-binding, webapi, iformfile

Im trying to create dotnet 7 webapi endpoint with streaming file upload but I always get an error that I cant overcome. I'm Trying to use a library called UploadStream, Github page: https://github.com/ma1f/uploadstream

Error:

> System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder.GetFormFilesAsync(String modelName, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ICollection`1 postedFiles)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinder.BindPropertyAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ModelMetadata property, IModelBinder propertyBinder, String fieldName, String modelName)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinder.BindPropertiesAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Int32 propertyData, IReadOnlyList`1 boundProperties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinder.BindModelCoreAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Int32 propertyData)

It happens on line 31 in ControllerExtensions.cs with the method `controller.TryUpdateModelAsync<T>(model, prefix: "", valueProvider : form);`

Controller Code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPresentationV1()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 100];
            List<IFormFile> files = new List<IFormFile>();

            var model = await this.StreamFiles<UploadPresentationCommand>(async x =>
            {
                using (var stream = x.OpenReadStream())
                    while (await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0) ;
                files.Add(x);
            });

            return Ok("");
        }
```

Model UploadPresentationCommand:

```
    public class UploadPresentationCommand
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PresentationContent { get; set; }

        public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to use a disable form model binding attribute what I found in the microsoft documentation:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
    {
        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            var factories = context.ValueProviderFactories;
            factories.RemoveType<FormValueProviderFactory>();
            factories.RemoveType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>();
            factories.RemoveType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>();
        }

        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

What I found out, somehow even with this attribute the `List<IFormFile> Images` gets binded from the request to the model (For example if I specify it in the endpoint parameter like that `[FromForm] UploadPresentationCommand uploadPresentationCommand`, The files are binded, but the other two properties are not, so I assume that this is the root of the problem and I dont know how to disable this type of binding entirely, also im not sure if it could help.

Comment: Hi @GH_Dev, are you sure the error occurs in `controller.TryUpdateModelAsync<T>(model, prefix: "", valueProvider : form);` instead of `section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();`?

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, looks like I misread the exception message, thats because the debugging was strange too because it did not throw the exception right away when I hit that line only some lines later (I went line by line with the debugger). This part is also stated in one of the issues from the issues section from the library, and I found it elsewhere on the internet too, but I was not successful fixing this exception.

Comment: Also note that I have HTTPS redirection disabled so that wont break the upload.